# VPN/Proxy/IP changer

Tags: networking, proxy, vpn

guys! I apologize in advance if this question comes up often here. I'm a very beginner using Ubuntu and I'd appreciate any help to keep using it. I usually work with a mac and a windows computer, but now I've decided to install ubuntu on my windows laptop. It's been great so far (I've installed 12.04 precise pangolin). However I travel a lot and often I use some websites and softwares which do not work in the other countries where I've been travelling.

While using Windows I used FlyVPN and TunnelBear to fake an ip adress in USA or UK (where I currently live).

So, could you guys tell me how can I make the same? I've been searching on google for days and I still didn't find a solution.. maybe my lack of knowledge when it comes to ubuntu..
I appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [`Tor`](https://www.torproject.org/) which is the best Anonymity open source software 
How to install instruction [`Link`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en)

that run on local host (127.0.0.1:9050) port 9050 on socket5
 
and you can use this cool add-on [`Proxy Selector`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/proxy-selector/)to switch between the tor network or direct connection. 

 hope this will help you :)